# Submodule embeddable in a finitely generated module

Tags: modules, ac.commutative-algebra

I have a terminology question. For a commutative ring $A$ (not necessarily Noetherian), $A$-modules that are isomorphic to an $A$-submodule of a finitely generated $A$-module form a fairly good class of $A$-modules, e.g., it is closed by sub and quotient modules, and by direct sum. I would like to know if there is already an established name for this notion of modules.

Comment: Leave off finitely generated, and the answer is "projective".

Comment: I would have said "sub-finitely generated" (and don't understand Allen's comment, projective seems unrelated).

Comment: I think "bounded A-module", or "finitely bounded A-module", would have been a good name. But "bounded module" is already used to mean a different notion. I would like to ask, especially to English native speakers, for opinions. It will be used in the second volume of the book "Foundations of rigid geometry" with K. Fujiwara.

Comment: This condition appears naturally in the theory of finite state automata (with weights) and I have always be embarrassed with the lack of well-known terminology.